# Responsive design & displaying nested lists

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently trying to teach myself some responsive design, and just wanted some opinions on the best way of tackling the problem that I have. I've decided to start by making an existing project of mine (https://github.com/antm611/MusicServerGUI) functional on a mobile device. I'm going to do this by stripping out the Twitter Bootstrap library and using my own CSS.

As you can see from the screenshot on GitHub, the main 'Albums' view has a pane on the left to select an artist, and a pane on the right to display albums by the selected artist. I have achieved this with two separate unordered lists. However, my plan for devices with smaller viewports will be to display this as one list, arranged in the following structure:

- Artist 1
- Artist 2 (selected)

  - Album 1
  - Album 2 (selected)

    - Track 1
    - Track 2
  - Album 3
- Artist 3

If I was just designing the mobile site standalone, I would achieve this with nested lists (as above). However, this would require the actual HTML to be different. As I understand responsive design, the goal is normally to use the same markup, but change the way it is displayed to the user based on media queries.

If someone could point me in the 'best' way to tackle this sort of problem, I would be very grateful.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd create one `div` element within the same albums `UL` that you have on normal screens, the only difference is that it would have `display: none` initially, and you'd change that to `display: block` on smaller viewports and at the same time set the current `albums` column to `display: none`. So, basically, it's a switch thing (show/hide).

Comment: I'm not keen to duplicate data in the DOM (even if it's hidden) as there will be a large amount when it's all loaded. As I'm using the angularJS library, I could potentially use an ng-show though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then all the better with Angular. The idea is to have empty element which you would show and populate with data (forward data to that div on smaller viewport instead of large left column).